When trying to find the quartiles for discrete data, do we round to the nearest whole number?
I have 2 cases:
First, I want to find the first quartile to the set data: 1,2,3,4,5.
Normally we calculate the qaurtile as:
Now $Q_1 = \frac{2+1}{2} = 1.5$.
But they never state if its continuous (i.e., the data is the set of heights, weights, etc.) or discrete(i.e., number of people, goals scored, etc.)
But suppose they do state it's discrete, do we leave $Q_1 = 1.5$ as is, or round to 2?
Second
When trying to find the quartiles for grouped discrete data, do we round to the nearest whole number?
I can't find a single clear answer on if we round for grouped discrete data (when using a Ogive~Cumulative frequency graph to find quartiles)
Example: The number of errors received while programming per day for the first 16 days was recorded in a frequency table.
(an example of this data could be: 0,1,1,8,7,9, 10,11,11,11,19,15, 21,25,29,35 )
(y-axis is c.Frequency, x-axis errors)
$Q_1 = 6.5$, do we round to 7, or leave as 6.5?

I would greatly appreciate any insight you can offer me on this problem.

Could you please tell us what you mean by "discrete data" and why this distinction, whatever it might be, ought to affect how quantiles are computed?

@whuber, isn't discrete data is data that can be counted? For example if the data given for my first question was the number of goals scored for the first 5 matches, then it will be discrete data set, But if it were to be a set of heights, then it would be a continuous data set. (both ungrouped)
I am not sure whether discrete or not should affect the quartiles, or are the quartiles more of a "mathematical concept", not related to the type of data set?

All data can be counted.  Quantiles concern distributions of numbers. They don't care about what those numbers mean.  This suggests that your question is really about how you intend to use and interpret quantiles.  In that regard, I find it interesting to compare your question to a similar one about another kind of estimate: the mean.  Consider binary (0/1) data, which are as discrete as one can get. Would you necessarily round their mean--which will therefore always equal 0 or 1?  If so, what would motivate you to do that?

The answer, as with so many questions about quantiles, is "different people do it different ways"
The basic issue I think you're asking about is whether a quantile should be rounded to be a possible value of the variable, assuming we know what the possible values are, when it would otherwise be interpolated between two distinct values.  For example, if $X$ has 5 values of 0 and 5 values of 1, should the median be forced to be 0 or 1 rather than 0.5?
There are two subquestions

what if the valid values are the actual values, such as a count 1,2,3,4 when the count is what's recorded?
what if the discrete values themselves arose by rounding, such as age to the nearest year?

The case for rounding the quantile is weaker in the second setting, I would argue.
Now, what do people actually do in data analysis? Well, the R quantile() function (which a non-negligible number of people use for data analysis) has 9 options. Three of them are specifically designed for discontinuous quantile functions. Of these, two round and the other one interpolates.  The six that aren't designed specifically for discontinuous quantiles all interpolate.
From a practical computing viewpoint this raises the question of how you know the valid values and how you know whether ties occurred naturally or by rounding.. Most statistical software doesn't support the sort of variable type information that you'd need for the software to make this decision.
So, overall: I think there's a case for not interpolating when the variable is genuinely discrete (rather than rounded), but given actually existing software I think it must be fairly rare for people to make that distinction in practice.
I wouldn't be at all surprised if some textbooks made the distinction, and I did worry about it in earlier versions of my survey package (which is how I know that not many people care).

Thank you for your reply
